# How to make gpg work, after I restore deleted keys

Tags: linux, security, gnupg

I removed all `~/.gnupg` directory. But I could grep data, that looks like on `pubring.kbx` and keys in `private-keys-v1.d`. I don't no private keys keygrip. Can I some how export public and private keys from this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I separated public key and private keys data from binary grep result. Added public key to `pubring.kbx`. Generated keygrip for private keys and put it into `private-keys-v1.d`. And gpg could successfully show me my keys.